# SQL Server Agents Jobs Fails

Tags: sql-server, ssis-2012

I tried to Run SSIS Package from Integration Services Catalog then all package run Successfully but while try to run jobs from SQL Server Agents then all jobs fails

got error message like

[image]

I saw I have all access to run jobs
guys, have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your Agent login doesn't have permission to make the connection.

Comment: I saw Sql Server Agent Running with NTServices/SQLSERVERAGENT and this login have access to run both MSDB and SSIDB And while checking from SQl Server Agent my windows User as a Owner and i think i have all permission to run jobs so where do i have to check further ???

Comment: Yes you need to make sure the SQLSERVERAGENT has permission to make the ODBC connection that the package needs to make.

Comment: so do you have any idea how can i make ODBC connection by using SQLSERVERAGENT?

Comment: If you give SQLSERVERAGENT all the same permissions as your account, then it should work.